# How to bind volume in docker-compose for portainer docker swarm deployment?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, portainer

I am new to docker / docker swarm and I just setup a cluster with 4 pi nodes as a docker swarm. I also have on all 4 pis a shared volume taped with the same path /mnt/docker.
Now I want to deploy portainer with docker compose. I use the default docker compose file from portioners documentation. It works great but now I would like to change the compose file to use /mnt/docker/portainer/data as a persistent storage for all portainer data. So in case of a rebuild or failure I could just start from there again.

But I can't seem to get it working. There are multiple mount points under volumes, but none of them seems to work as the portainer data never gets written to the nfs share path.

What do I need to add to get a persistent data volume bind in docker compose?

This is my compose file so far:

````
services:
  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes
    networks:
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce
    command: -H tcp://tasks.agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - portainer_data:/data
    networks:
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]

networks:
  agent_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

volumes:
  portainer_data:```

Thanks a lot for your help!
````